# execute code when select is clicked in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView and a select link in the GrdiView, when the item is selected I want it to read the contents to a textbox below the GridView. The only way I can think is by accessing the behind code for the onClick function of the select link. The problem is I am unsure how to do this.

UPDATED jams method:

C# code

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

front code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
GridLines="None">
```

UPDATE my method:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    ds.Tables["Comments"].Rows[i]["Comment"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

also tried this but I get an error -> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position -1.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's a really straightforward thing explained in MANY articles already.

Comment: edited to show what I have tried.

Comment: your method does nothing and my method gives the error you can see both and the error message in my questions updated.

Comment: I am just started C 2 days ago, Thanks for the help, turns out I had misunderstand the [0] I needed to set the index to [1] for the correct column. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach OnSelectedIndexChanged event with your gridview

```
<asp:GridView OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Then in code behind you could do:

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;// you will get the selected row
    someLabel.Text =  row.Cells[0].Text;
  }
```

Comment: If I try this I get -> 'ASP.admin_default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'EventHandler'

Comment: @user1389384, I meant put your event handler, check my edited answer

Comment: no parse errors but the text doesnt appear in the textbox, edited my questions to show your code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Once you attach to the selectedindexchanged event you need to also set up some datakeys so you can retrieve values from your grid.  See sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx).

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // Determine the index of the selected row.
  int index = CustomersGridView.SelectedIndex;

  // Display the primary key value of the selected row.
  Message.Text = "The primary key value of the selected row is " +
    CustomersGridView.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString() + ".";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use oORowCommand event of the grid view and pass the command argument and commandName to the same event as a attribute value. Then i think it will work.